# Repeating a part of code in python 3.4.4

Tags: python

I want to repeat my code.I want to when user for example writes hello the code print hello and then it replays the input to user write something different.When i use while True for the second time when user writes something else the output of last replays not output of the last input.
Please run code then you will get what im saying.

```
percent_of_loading = 0
admin_name = 'John'
admin_familyname = 'Doe'
admin_fullname = 'John Doe'
admin_age = 15
percent_of_loading += 100
u = input('What Are Your Commands?\n=>')
def A():
    input('What Are Your Commands?\n=>')
def B():
    print('Error 5:Access Is Denied!')
    A()
if u == 'admin_name':
B()
elif u == 'admin_familyname':
    B()
elif u == 'admin_fullname':
    B()
elif u == 'admin_age':
    B()
elif u == 'hello':
    print('Hello, My Friend')
    A()
else:
    print('Error 404')
    A()
```

Comment: Then why not use a `while` loop?

Comment: Show the `while` that is not working, with the full trace and error messages.  If you do that you can often work out the error yourself.  If all you do is copy and paste other people's code then you will never learn to program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you're code to repeat, you can use a looping construct from the language (like `while`, `for`).

```
def a_functioin()
    pass

a_function() # this runs once
```

to run a piece of code for a given number of times (like 100 times exactly), or to run the code for all the elements in a list a `for` loop is useful:

```
for i in range(100):
    a_function()
```

to run a piece of code as long as a condition holds true, a `while` loop is helpful:

```
def condition():
    pass # implement some condition, returning True, or False

while condition():
   a_function()
```

For the above code, it seems like a command interface that keeps reading from user input, process the input (might print something out) and then waits for the next input, and that's why a repetition is required.
If so, it looks like an infinite loop is required, like this:

(I brought function definitions outside of the loop so they're defined once, but are called in the loop):

```
def A():
    return input('What Are Your Commands?\n=>')
def B():
    print('Error 5:Access Is Denied!')

while True:
    u = A()
    if u == 'admin_name':
        B()
    elif u == 'admin_familyname':
        B()
    elif u == 'admin_fullname':
        B()
    elif u == 'admin_age':
        B()
    elif u == 'hello':
        print('Hello, My Friend')
```

(I'm not changing/improving a lot, so the answer to the original question is easier to see in the code).

Just for a reminder, if you're implementing a program to keep asking users for input and process them like this, the [cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module from standard library is helpful.